# Printing the 3 highest integers from an array without sorting

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program that prints the highest integers from a collection of student's grades array, but the code keeps returning me the same values each time it returns me a value.

So far this is the code:

```
class BestGrades {
public static void main(String args[]){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            int grade[] = new int[6];
            int best[] = new int[3];

            System.out.println("Enter the student's grade...");

            for(int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++){

                    grade[i] = sc.nextInt();

                    for(int a = 0; a < best.length; a++){
                            if(grade[i] > best[a]){
                                    best[a] = grade[i];
                            }
                    }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < best.length; i++){
                    System.out.println("Best degrees are: "+best[i]);
            }
    }
```

}

As I said, the code will always return me the same highest value 3x.
Pardon me for any mistakes, first time asking here.

Comment: Why without sorting?

Comment: Do you need the `grade` array? It'll work fine without it.

Comment: @jagemue Sorting is an inefficient way to solve this problem. It can easily be done in O(n). It's presumably a requirement of a course assignment or interview to make you think outside of the box, which will also help in plenty of real-world situations where there's just too much data for sorting to be a good idea when you can get the result from a single pass over the data.

Comment: I think you meant to put a `break` in your if-statement, but that could still remove the 2nd biggest value and replace it with the biggest one.

Comment: @jagemue I just want create the program without sorting because I've learned array recently and I need to exercise my knowledge on it better. Student things I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to keep a track of which is the lower grade in you best array an replace just that one

```
class BestGrades {
public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int grade[] = new int[6];
        int best[] = new int[3];

        System.out.println("Enter the student's grade...");

        for(int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++){

                grade[i] = sc.nextInt();

                boolean better = false;
                int lowerIndex = 0;

                for(int a = 0; a < best.length; a++){
                        if(grade[i] > best[a]){
                                better = true;
                        }
                        if(best[a] < best[lowerIndex]){
                            lowerIndex = a;
                        }
                }
                if(better){
                    best[lowerIndex] = grade[i];
                }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < best.length; i++){
                System.out.println("Best degrees are: "+best[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can drop `better` and just do `grade[i] > best[lowerIndex]`, then also start the loop from 1.

Comment: Thanks for answering David, that was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int a = 0; a < best.length; a++){
    if(grade[i] > best[a]){
        for(int b = a + 1; b < best.length; b++){
            best[b] = best[b - 1];
        }
        best[a] = grade[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this answer easier and faster for others to understand.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but can you please provide an explanation for your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but something like this should work.  It finds the minimum value in your best array, and if the new value is greater than that, it is one of the best values and replaces that original min value.  Similar to David's answer, but a little simpler.

```
// Start best values at negative infinite so that the worst grade
// is still better that what's initially stored
best = {Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE};

for(int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++){
    grade[i] = sc.nextInt();

    // find min value of the max values
    // start by setting first value as the min
    int minIndex = 0;

    for(int a = 1; a < best.length; a++){
        if(best[a] < best[minIndex]) {
            minIndex = a;
        }
    }

    // place new grade into best array if it is better
    // than the worst best value
    if(grade[i] > best[minIndex])
        best[minIndex] = grade[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to attack a problem like this is to break it into smaller pieces. One way is top-down - when something looks too hard to do in-line, call a method (that doesn't exist) to do it. Then write that method.

```
  for( grade : grades) {
      replaceLowestIfHigher(grade, best);
  }
```

Now we just need to write `replaceLowestIfHigher()`:

```
  public void replaceLowestIfHigher(int grade, int[] target) {
      int indexOfLowest = findIndexOfLowest(target);

      if(grade > target[indexOfLowest]) {
         target[indexOfLowest] = grade;
      }
  }
```

... and now we have to write `findIndexOfLowest()`:

```
 public int findIndexOfLowest(int[] array) { 
      int indexOfLowest=0;
      for(int i=1; i<array.length; i++) {
         if(array[i] < array[indexOfLowest]) {
              indexOfLowest = i;
         }
      }
      return indexOfLowest;
 }
```

The only problem with this is that you hunt through the destination array for the lowest value even though it's likely you've done it before for the same values. There are various ways you could store this knowledge - for example, you could create a class to manage the "best" array, that remembers where the lowest is, and only recalculates when the data changes:

```
public class BestGrades {
    private int[] grades = new int[3];
    private int indexOfLowest = 0;

    public int[] getGrades() {
        return grades;
    }

    public void replaceLowestIfHigher(int grade) {
       if(grade > grades[indexOfLowest]) {
          grades[indexOfLowest] = grade;
          updateIndexOfLowest();
       }
    }

    private void updateIndexOfLowest() {
        indexOfLowest = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<target.length; i++) {
            if(grades[i] < grades[indexOfLowest]) {
                indexOfLowest = i;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

However, most mature Java programmers would use a sorted collection to achieve this.

Comment: Breaking into other pieces(methods)? I might look better into this, thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to solve this problem in a functional style. Using the previously described strategy:

1. iterate through array and find if current element is superior to one of the items in the best note array.
2. if so then find the smallest best note in the array and capture its position
3. copy the current item to the best note array using the position found in 2.

This is the functional alternative which can capture N best notes:

```
public static int[] findNHighest2(int[] array, int limit) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length).boxed().collect(() -> new int[limit], (a, i) -> { // collect in array with specified size.
        IntStream.range(0, limit).boxed().filter(j -> array[i] > a[j]).findFirst().ifPresent(k -> { // finding if there is an item larger than the best ones
            int minPos = findMinPos(a, limit); // find the minimum of the best ones
            a[minPos] = array[i]; // copy the new best item to our best item array
        });
    }, (a, i) -> {});
}

private static int findMinPos(int[] array, int limit) {
    return IntStream.range(0, limit)
            .reduce((i,j) -> array[i] > array[j] ? j : i)
            .getAsInt();
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int[] arr = {9, 3,1, 9, 2, 7, 11, 2, 1, -1, 100, 8, 9, 199, 2};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(findNHighest(arr.clone(), 6)));
}
```

The result on the console:

```
[9, 199, 11, 9, 100, 9]
```